# Weird div behaviour in Firefox 17.0.4

Tags: html, css, firefox, geometry

I'm using a div to create a circle, to act as a period at the end of my headings.

This period/div worked fine for Safari, IE, Chrome and also FF just up until some weeks ago.

I can't remember any changes I've done, besides increasing the heading's font size, which made the period loose it's correct position. After correcting this, it's now suddenly approx 10-20 pixels below the right position in FF 17.0.4, but in correct position for IE, Safari and Chrome.

The period looks like this; (CSS)

```
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
background-color: rgb(252, 193, 54);
border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
margin-left: 651px;
margin-top: -125px;
```

The margin-left/top is to locate it correctly... so I can't change that just for the FF... or!?

Any ideas why it's suddenly has moved only in FF?

Do you need my homepage to get the whole picture?

Comment: Keep it simple. You don't and should not use additional `div` just for that. If what you call heading is a `h1`, then use a pseudo element: `h1:after { content:"."; font-size: 25px; }`

Comment: Why worry about such an old browser? It was release in [March 2013](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/17.0.4/releasenotes/), and Firefox's autoupdater will have wiped it from the face of the earth

Comment: I had no idea I could use; h1:after!!! Lovely solution! Many thanks Jose! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not the best way, but it helped me a lot to sort out my browser compatibility problems. If u still face this problems u can target your CSS classes only for Firefox:

sample (inside css file):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .my_class{
       //attributes that will affect only Firefox
    }
}
```

Comment: I used Jose's solution by simply using the; "h1:after..." :-)